# Mapping custom POCO in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

So I have a small issue with converting a string to a boolean when EF maps to my POCO. I created custom POCOs and I have one that has a boolean property called "IsActive". But, in the database the tables column "IsActive", that maps to the POCOs property, is a string. It's either 'Y' or 'N'.

EF doesn't like this, so I'm wondering if there's a way to tell it to convert the string to a boolean through a custom method?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested it by myself.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4)

Create complex type definition in your edmx.

```
<ComplexType Name="IsActiveWrapper" > 
          <Property Type="string" Name="Value" Nullable="false" /> 
</ComplexType>
```

Create complex type

```
public class IsActiveWrapper
{
    private bool isActive;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive ? "Y" : "N";
        }

        set
        {
            isActive = "Y".Equals(value);
        }
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set { isActive = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator IsActiveWrapper(bool isActive)
    {
        return new IsActiveWrapper { IsActive = isActive };
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(IsActiveWrapper wrap)
    {
        if (wrap == null) return false;
        return wrap.IsActive;
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this

```
public class TestIsActive
{
    public virtual IsActiveWrapper IsActive { get; set; }
}
var test = new TestIsActive { IsActive = true };
```

Comment: Forget to point it... Thanks to @Roger Alsing
In queries you have to write something like this

var query = 
            from test in ctx.TestIsActive
            where test.IsActive.Value == "Y" 
            select test;

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to set my Entity property to Boolean? That may be an issue....I thought about creating a tempIsActive property in my Entity that maps to the db string and then have my IsActive Entity property get the tempIsActive property value and convert it to a Boolean. But, I have just tied my Entity to my database...

Comment: You would be able to set your Entity property to Boolean due to implicit operators, see the last line. 
As far as I know the only incovenience with this solution is with Linq queries.

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice that. I'll give it a try and see if it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I have never worked with Complex Type so I'm sure I'm missing something. How do I link my IsActiveWrapper to my IsActive property on my Entity?

Comment: I'm getting this error - "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
No corresponding object layer type could be found for the conceptual type 'TestProj.IsActiveWrapper'."

Comment: I got it to work! I generalized IsActiveWrapper to BooleanWrapper and now I can use it on any of my Entities that have booleans. Thank you for your help!